# Force user authentication in URL dispatcher of Django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I would like to restrict a specific path to authenticated users in *urls.py*. I know how to do it in *views.py*, the problem is that this is a module which I have installed using pip, so I do not handle it in my views, and I do not want to modify the source code of this module.

```
    ...
    path('thispath/', include('module.urls')),
    ...
```

May I force an authentication in *urls.py ?* Or should do it in *views.py* as usual (or using decorators):

```
request.user.is_authenticated
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. It should be done using *decorators*, but as it is an include, the default login_required decorator does not work.

So, one solution could be with *[django-decorator-include](https://github.com/twidi/django-decorator-include)*

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from decorator_include import decorator_include
...
path('thispath/', decorator_include(login_required,'module.urls')),
...
```